# Component not getting loaded in react routing

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Im trying to implement routing in react.
Here's my index.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter,Route, Switch, withRouter,Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import {Home} from './components/Home.jsx';
import {AddUser} from './components/AddUser.jsx';

class App extends React.Component {
 render() {
    return(
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact render={() => <Redirect to='/home' />} />
                <Route path="/home" exact component={Home} />
                <Route path="/adduser" exact component={AddUser} />                    
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
 }
}

render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

This my home component file

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Home extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        users : []
    }
}

  render() {
   return (
    <div>hello</div>
   );
 }
}
```

Application redirects as expected but the component is not getting loaded.
There are no errors in the console, I could find various examples of react routing most of them were of previous router versions.

Kindly help me understand this issue.
Thanks in advance

Comment: so localhost:portNum/adduser doesn't go to AddUserComponent? but your Home component gets loaded and redirected when in root route '/' ?

Comment: It works as expected in codesandbox, https://codesandbox.io/s/74mp3pmpw1, Can you provide a reproducible demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When importing the `default` export do not use `{}`

So, since you export your components as `default`, you should use

```
import Home from './components/Home.jsx';
import AddUser from './components/AddUser.jsx';
```

demo at https://codesandbox.io/s/5wqx9x2724

---

In general see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import